# Anime about a boy and 2 girls and they had to find these mechas

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I was trying to find this old anime I used to watch, it was about a boy and 2 girls (1 with red hair and I remember the other one had blue hair) and they had to find these mechas.

I remember there was one episode where they went to a resort and they had to do an anagram phrase to gain entry, inside they found people using their sweat and selling them as energy drinks (sorry I remember the scene clearly but not the title of the anime).

Answer (score -2):

Your description is reminiscent of *Neon Genesis Evangelion*. The three main protagonists are a boy (Shinji Ikari) and two girls (Asuka Langley, who has red hair, and Rei Ayanami, who has blue hair). They're not looking for mechas, they pilot mechas called EVAs to fight invading aliens called Angels.

I've never seen it, so I don't know whether there's an episode like the one you describe, but given how *weird* I've heard it is, it's entirely plausible.

Comment: I have seen  Neon Genesis Evangelion, the "The three main protagonists are a boy (Shinji Ikari) and two girls (Asuka Langley, who has red hair, and Rei Ayanami, who has blue hair)" matches, but the part of using their sweat and selling them as energy drinks, Doesnt Match,

Comment: I understand the downvotes, but I'm leaving this answer up just in case anyone else sees "red-haired girl, blue-haired girl, mecha" and makes the same mistake I did.